# Django multiple forms on one page with inherited models

Tags: python, django, forms

For my current Django project I have built a page that uses 3 ModelForms.

The entire page is supposed to let hotels register on the site. 
So the first ModelForm is from the Hotel model

Next I want the user to enter 2 forms for images, a main image and a background image. These 2 models are inherited from a basic Image class.
So in this case both images will use the title field, coming from the base class.

Now When I enter a new hotel into the form and also add the 2 images, both images get the same title.
When I take a look at the html code this does makes sense because the input fields both have the same name="title".

For the rest the form works just as expected, it is just this one issue.
Of course I could just take the title field and put them into the child classes as child_class_1_title and child_class_2_title, but that would just break the entire OOP and DRY principle.

How can I make sure that each form pushes the right data into the database?
Thanks a lot in advance.

This is my code for the forms:

```
class HotelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ('name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'city', 'website', 'email', 'phone', 'description', 'short_description', 'number_of_rooms', 'facilities',
                  'activities', 'environment', 'hotel_type')
        widgets = {
            'facilities': CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }

class HotelGeneralImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelGeneralImage
        fields = ('title', 'hotel_general_image')
        widgets = {
            'hotel_general_image': FileWidget()
        }

class HotelBackgroundImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelBackgroundImage
        fields = ('title', 'hotel_background_image')
        widgets = {
            'hotel_background_image': FileWidget()
        }
```

And the view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def hotel_registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hotel_form = HotelForm(request.POST, instance=Hotel())
        hotel_general_image_form = HotelGeneralImageForm(request.POST, instance=HotelGeneralImage())
        hotel_background_image_form = HotelBackgroundImageForm(request.POST, instance=HotelBackgroundImage())
        if hotel_form.is_valid() and hotel_general_image_form.is_valid() and hotel_background_image_form.is_valid():
            new_hotel = hotel_form.save()
            new_hotel_general_image = hotel_general_image_form.save(commit=False)
            new_hotel_general_image.hotel = new_hotel
            new_hotel_general_image.save()
            new_hotel_background_image = hotel_background_image_form.save(commit=False)
            new_hotel_background_image.hotel = new_hotel
            new_hotel_background_image.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('registered')
    else:
        hotel_form = HotelForm(instance=Hotel())
        hotel_general_image_form = HotelGeneralImageForm(instance=HotelGeneralImage())
        hotel_background_image_form = HotelBackgroundImageForm(instance=HotelBackgroundImage())

    context = {'hotel_form': hotel_form,
               'hotel_general_image_form': hotel_general_image_form,
               'hotel_background_image_form': hotel_background_image_form
               }
    context.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('hotel/hotel-registration-form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form prefix will solve your issue:

```
hotel_general_image_form = HotelGeneralImageForm(prefix='general', ...)
hotel_background_image_form = HotelBackgroundImageForm(prefix='background', ...)
```

This way each form will have its own prefix hence will not interfere with other forms.

More in docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix